# Cases of Partial Fraction Decomposition

Tags: integration

How many cases are there in integration using partial fractions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by your question - could you explain a bit more what you mean by a "case"?

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help Sir @MarkBennet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I would say there are $5$ cases.

Assume you have a rational function $\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where the degree of $q(x)$ exceeds the degree of $p(x)$.

**Case $1$**: $q(x)$ is a product of distinct linear factors

*Example:* Consider $q(x)=\dfrac{x}{(x+3)(x-1)}$

**Case $2$**: $q(x)$ is a product of linear factors, where some of these factors are repeated

*Example:* Consider $q(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{(x+4)^2(x-2)}$

**Case $3$**: $q(x)$ is a product of distinct irreducible quadratic factors

*Example:* Consider $q(x)=\dfrac{x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+3)}$

**Case $4$**: $q(x)$ is a product of irreducible quadratic factors, where some are repeated

*Example:* Consider $q(x)=\dfrac{2x-1}{(x^2+x+1)^3}$

**Case $5$**: $q(x)$ is some mixture of the above cases.

*Example:* Consider $\dfrac{3x-2}{(x-2)^2(x^2+x+2)}$

Consider another example, which has been worked to the decomposition stage of the solution.

\begin{align}
&\frac{2x-1}{(x-1)^2(x^2+x+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{Ex+F}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\\
\end{align}

Then, you can do what you normally do for partial fractions and equate the coefficients.

Comment: Sir, can you give me an example of case number 5? @Sujaan Kunalan

Comment: Sure, give me a moment. I'll edit it in.